# Returning tuple to API call with changed parameter names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tuples

I guess I could not explain it better in the title.
Sorry for that.

I'm returning a tuple containing and `ID` and a `name`.

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> tupleList= new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
foreach (Person person in people)
    tupleList.Add(person.GetIdName());
```

`GetIdName` is defined in the `People` class as follows:

```
public Tuple<int, string> GetIdName()
{
    return new Tuple<int, string>(ID, nome);
}
```

Now, all this is called by client via API in this

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Tuple<int, string>>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetPeople(int id)
{
    return Ok(tupleList)
}
```

What I get on client side is:

```
[{"m_Item1":1,"m_Item2":"Name 1"},{"m_Item1":2,"m_Item2":"Name 2"}]
```

Is there an way to set the `m_Item1` to something else?

Comment: Instead of Tuple why cant you use ViewModel for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to make change the definition, Create View Model like below,

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

So your code will be,

```
List<MyViewModel> tupleList= new List<MyViewModel>();
foreach (Person person in people)
    tupleList.Add(person.GetIdName());
```

Also Change your method `GetIdName` Accordingly to return `MyViewModel` object