# Tuple not returning from Asp.Net Core Web Api method

Tags: c#, tuples, blazor-webassembly, webapi

I have this method in my web api:

```
[HttpGet("GetPerson/{id}")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public async Task<(Person, List<ContactData>)> GetPerson(int id = 0)
{                
    Data.ThePerson person = new Data.ThePerson();
    List<ContactData> cDatas = person.contactDatas.Where(it => it.ContactId == id).ToList();
    var p = person.persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    return (p, cDatas);        
}
```

But the method returns `(, )` in the client! How to correct this?

Client:

```
public async Task<(Person, List<ContactData>)> GetPerson(int id)
{
    var tuple = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<(Person, List<ContactData>)>($"api/account/GetPerson/{id}");
    return tuple;
}
```

The server and client methods work when it only returns a Person object but converting it to tuple returns `(, )`. also I can see in the server that correct tuple builds and returns but in the client it is `(, )`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual HTTP request and HTTP response (headers and bodies) you send/get when you use the `GetPerson()` service call. Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961133/returning-tuple-to-api-call-with-changed-parameter-names and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005989/using-a-c-sharp-7-tuple-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api-controller

Comment: Just to clarify `Data.ThePerson person = new Data.ThePerson();`; the constructor of ThePerson returns an object, which contains a collection "persons", that presumably includes all the persons in the repository?  This seems remarkably inefficient, as well as being unnatural nomenclature (a noun in the singular housing a collection of itself in the plural).  Why do you not have a constructor that simply takes an id?

Comment: The backend is not yet designed I use static data for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be related to serialization and deserialization of the tuple when returning it from the API.

You can use a simple class to hold both the `Person` and `List<ContactData>` as properties. Use this class as the return type for your API method instead of a tuple.

```
public class PersonData
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public List<ContactData> ContactData { get; set; }
}
```

Modify your API method to return the `PersonData` class:

```
[HttpGet("GetPerson/{id}")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public async Task<PersonData> GetPerson(int id = 0)
{                
    Data.ThePerson person = new Data.ThePerson();
    List<ContactData> cDatas = person.contactDatas.Where(it => it.ContactId == id).ToList();
    var p = person.persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

    return new PersonData
    {
        Person = p,
        ContactData = cDatas
    };
}
```

Update your client method to handle the `PersonData` class:

```
public async Task<PersonData> GetPerson(int id)
{
    return await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PersonData>($"api/account/GetPerson/{id}");
}
```